# I have fetched date from mysql in python and I want to add current time eg. 2020-08-25T04:00:00 like this

Tags: python

I have tried this:

```py
import datetime
    
dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 12)
tm = datetime.time(1, 30)
    
combined = dt.combine(dt, tm)
    
print(combined)
```

but the output is:

`2012-02-12 01:30:00`

Comment: You can use datetime.timedelta (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) or dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta (https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#module-dateutil.relativedelta)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

# current date and time
now = datetime.now()
```

This would help you get the time now.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the lack of T between the date and time, the following will format it that way:

```
combined.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
'2012-02-12T01:30:00'
```

Look at strftime if you need to change the formatting some other way.